# License Plate Permutations

Tags: discrete-mathematics, permutations

A state has changed its license plate numbering system for the three largest counties. Before the
change, each plate had the number 1, 2, or 3, followed by **either one or two letters**, followed by 3 digits. After the change, each plate has three letters followed by three numbers. How many more plates can the state issue under the new system?

My current attempt:

First, I found the second part of the question. There are $26*26*26*10*10*10 = 17,576,000$ possible plates under the new system.

However, I'm having some trouble with the "either" in the bolded font of the problem.

Obviously we have $3$ possible choices for the first number. 
There are 10 choices for each digit, so $10*10*10$. 
So we currently have $3 * 10 * 10 * 10$.

If the keyword is 'either', what should I do? Do I even need to acknowledge the fact the plate can only contain one letter? This could multiply it by $26$, or $26*26$.

Comment: Break into cases:  There is one letter  OR  there are two letters.  How many license plates fall under the first category?  How many fall under the second category?  Is there any intersection between these? (*no there isn't*).  Apply the [Rule of Sum](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_sum) and **add** the results together.

Comment: One way is to add the number of possibilities with one letter and the number with two letters. For this method to be valid, it's important that there is no overlap between the two possibilities. That's the case here, because you either have one letter or two letters, never both.

Comment: Another option if you prefer is to always use two spaces for the letters, but for the second space you may instead *leave it blank*.  You have $26$ choices for the first letter space, and $27$ choices for the second (since it can be a letter or blank).

Comment: I found that with one letter there are 78,000 possible plates, and 2,028,000 possible plates for two letters. Since they don't overlap, there are 2,106,000 possible plates for the old system.

With 17,576,000 plates in the new system, that means the answer to this question is 17,576,000 - 2,106,000 = 15,470,000 more possible plates under the new system.

@JMoravitz That second way is interesting. I did not think of it that way. Thanks for that!

Comment: I think the comments covered everything, but just as a rule of thumb, when you see the word "OR", there's a good chance you will be adding values.